# Remove duplicate element from the set in java

Tags: java, set

I have set of string array and i want to remove duplicate elements from this...

```
    String[] arr1 = {"a1","b1"};
    String[] arr2 = {"a2","b2"};
    Set<String[]> mySet = new HashSet<String[]>();
    mySet.add(arr1);
    mySet.add(arr2);
    mySet.add(new String[] {"a1","b1"});
    System.out.print(mySet.size());
```

Currently mySet looks like this:

```
[{"a1","b1"},{"a2","b2"},{"a1","b1"}]
```

But I want like this:

```
[{"a1","b1"},{"a2","b2"}]
```

I know some ways...

1. Every time I need to run inner loop and check whether its duplicate or not.
2. Can I override the set's behavior? (hashcode or equals)? ( i do not know how....)
3. Do I need to change data structure for this? (linkedhashset or list or any other suitable data structure for this?)

Comment: ok.. thanks... Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: i am reading and trying all the solutions... i will surely accept the answer, once i will try all the ways...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Arrays inherit from Object and don't override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods. A `HashSet` uses a `Map` implementation, which in turn, uses `hashCode` and `equals` to avoid duplicate elements.

You can use a `TreeSet` with a custom `Comparator` that compares the `String` arrays for equality.

```
Set<String[]> mySet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String[]>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
    return Arrays.equals(o1, o2)? 0 : Arrays.hashCode(o1) - Arrays.hashCode(o2);
  }

});
```

Note that this will only neglect duplicate arrays with the same corresponding elements. If the order of elements is different, it won't be considered as a duplicate.

If you want to be able to discard **unordered** duplicates, for e.g., `{a1, b1}` and `{b1, a1}`, use this:

```
@Override
public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
    int comparedHash = o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
    if(o1.length != o2.length) return comparedHash;
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(o1);
    for(String s : o2) {
        if(!list.contains(s)) return comparedHash;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thnaks... it works.... I have accepted the answer already.

Comment: That `TreeSet` won't work properly. The `Comparator` must implement a total ordering; in particular, the result of `compare(o1, o2)` must be the opposite of `compare(o2, o1)`.

Comment: @user2357112, Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have modified it to use the `hashCode`s for comparison so that `compare(o1, o2) + compare(o2, o1) == 0`. BTW by "won't work property", do you mean that the `TreeSet`'s iterator may miss out some elements or search operations(`contains`) may fail because all nodes will end up at the right of the tree's implementation?

Comment: That still won't work. Since "equal" arrays will usually have different hashcodes, you may end up in a situation where the comparator thinks `o1 < o2`, `o2 < o3`, and `o3 == o1`. As for "won't work properly", it's likely that insertion and search will both fail to detect that an element is already present.

Comment: @user2357112, I agree that with the second solution `contains(array)` wouldn't work unless the `array` is a reference to the same `array` that was `add`ed to the `Set`. Nonetheless, `add` and `iterator` will work. And the first one works for search operations too.

Answer (score 10):

The `array` hashcode is independent of the contents of the `array` (it inherits the `Object` hashcode, which uses the array's reference).

However, `List` would do what you want. It uses a hashcode based on the elements in the `List` . [From Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29):

```
int hashCode = 1;
for (E e : list)
    hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

---

**Example:**

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a1","b1");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a2","b2");
Set<List<String>> mySet = new HashSet<List<String>>();
mySet.add(list1);
mySet.add(list2);
mySet.add(Arrays.asList("a1","b1"));   // duplicate won't be added
System.out.print(mySet.size());        // size = 2
```

Comment: thanks buddy. this solution also works.... ( :( sorry i can accept the only one answer...)

Comment: the only problem is i have to convert the string arrays into list... which is quite lengthy....

Comment: +1 for the creative and different way for problem solution... and also for your description and link...

Comment: no problem, you're welcome bud!

Comment: You don't need to explicitly create an array for `Arrays.asList`; you can just use `Arrays.asList("a1", "b1")`.

Comment: wow, somehow I never realized that. Thank you!

Comment: @MananShah , thanks to user2357112's suggestion you might find this solution fits your needs better.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays uses `identity-based Object.hashCode()` implementation and there is no easy way to check if they are equal. If it all you still want to go ahead with your problem I would suggest you to use  `TreeSet` with Comparator

Though not fail proof approach, but you should be able to build fine tuned solution out of my example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] arr1 = {"a1","b1"};
            String[] arr2 = {"a2","b2"};
            Set<String[]> mySet = new TreeSet<String[]>(new ArrayComparator());
            mySet.add(arr1);
            mySet.add(arr2);
            mySet.add(new String[] {"a1","b1"});
            System.out.println(mySet.size());
            for(String[] aa: mySet){
                System.out.println(aa[0]+" , "+aa[1]);
            }
    }
}

 class ArrayComparator implements Comparator {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String[] ar1 =(String[]) o1;
        String[] ar2 =(String[]) o2;
        if(ar1.length!=ar2.length){
            return -1;
        }
        for(int count=0;count<ar1.length;count++){
            if(!ar1[count].equals(ar2[count])){
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: thanks man... i have tried and your solution works for me...

Comment: +1 for ArrayComparator....

Comment: srry i can accept the only one as a answer.... but thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a List implementation? The list.equals will compare elements in each list and determine equality.

```
List<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
arr1.add("a1");
arr1.add("b1");
List<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
arr2.add("a2");
arr2.add("b2");
Set<List<String>> mySet = new HashSet<List<String>>();
mySet.add(arr1);
mySet.add(arr2);

List<String> arr3 = new ArrayList<String>();
arr3.add("a1");
arr3.add("b1");
mySet.add(arr3);
System.out.print(mySet.size());
```

You suggest overriding equals and hashcode methods. HashSet is backed by a hashmap that uses the hashcode function as its key. So actually you need to override hashcode to represent your equals criteria.

One problem with this. I believe String and therefore String [] are declared as final, so you can't extend them :(

Comment: thanks man.... +1 for the idea(instead of string[] to list<string> )

Answer (score 2):

instead of taking array of string you can create a class Like this..

```
public class String1 implements Comparable<String1>{

String str1;
String str2;

public String1(String a, String b) {
    str1 = a;
    str2 = b;
}

public String getStr1() {
    return str1;
}
}

public String getStr2() {
    return str2;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "String1 [str1=" + str1 + ", str2=" + str2
            + "]";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(String1 o) {
    if(str1.contentEquals(o.getStr1()) && str2.contentEquals(o.getStr2()))  return 0 ; 
    return 1;

}


}
```

And after that insteed of string you can take this one class object.
replace HashSet with TreeSet. Like this .

```
     String1 arr1 =new String1("a1","b1");
     String1 arr2 =new String1("a2","b2");
     Set<String1> mySet = new TreeSet<String1>();
     mySet.add(arr1);
     mySet.add(arr2);
     mySet.add(new String1("a1","b1"));
     System.out.print(mySet.size());
     System.out.println(mySet.toString());
```

So this will sort as well this will check for duplicate also.

Comment: thanks Pankaj....  +1 for the clean example

Answer (score 2):

try to this code.............

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class setDemo {
static Set<String[]> mySet = new HashSet<String[]>();
static Set tempSet = new HashSet();
public static void main(String[] args) {

      String[] arr1 = {"a1","b1"};
      String[] arr2 = {"a2","b2"};

        addObject(arr1);
        addObject(arr2);
        addObject(new String[] {"a1","b1"});
        System.out.print(mySet.size());
       // System.out.println(tempSet);
}
public static void addObject(String[] o){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(Object obj:o){
        sb.append(obj.toString());
    }
    if(!tempSet.contains(sb.toString())){
        tempSet.add(sb.toString());
        mySet.add(o);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks ravi... +1 for the StringBuffer... its a really different problem solving approach then conventional (over riding of behavior) approach....

Comment: this code are multiple array object input and different size of array are allowed

Comment: Please do not use StringBuffer unless you have to, it was replaced by StringBuilder almost ten years ago.

Comment: peter lawrey thnx you are right.. StringBuffer is old its my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] arr1 = {"a1","b1"};
        String[] arr2 = {"a2","b2"};
        Set<String[]> mySet = new HashSet<String[]>();
        mySet.add(arr1);
        mySet.add(arr2);
        String str[] =new String[] {"a1","b1"}; 
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        boolean b =checkContains(str,mySet);
        long t2=System.nanoTime();
        long t = t2-t1;
        System.out.println("time taken : " + t );
        System.out.println(b);
        
        if(!b)
        {
            mySet.add(str);
         
        }

        
    }

    public static boolean checkContains(String[] str, Set mySet)
    {  
        Iterator it = mySet.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String[] arr = (String[])it.next();
            if(arr[0].equals(str[0]) && arr[1].equals(str[1]) )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        
         return false;
    }
```

OP :

> time taken : 184306
>
> true

Comment: +1 for the solution without overriding of any behavior...

Comment: You are welcome...But I've gotto admit... this approach is slower ( less efficient...) when compared to other approaches... I checked the time difference...

Answer (score 1):

Here instead of keeping Set you can use Set<**SomeClass**> and the override the hash and equals method for the class SomeClass so it will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you give sample example or some link? for the reference....

Comment: thanks Alpesh..... +1 for the idea(Use of class)